# Importing google fonts to Android studio without downloading

Tags: android-studio, flutter, webfonts, google-fonts

[The error][image: error]

Needed to import some fonts but without downloading them onto the device. Problem is, this code was done by our teacher and I have not even touched it yet. All he said was paste this and you are done but it doesn't seem to work, so is it possible that something is wrong with my installation of android studio or flutter?

Comment: Hover your cursor over it, what does the error say?

Comment: running flutter pub get should fix that assuming you have it in your pubspec.yaml